# Does it make sense to have hard drive containing Windows system files only indexed?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, search-indexing

I prefer to store all my documents, pictures and other stuff on drive D:. So the drive C: contains OS (Windows 10 pro) files only. Does it make sense to have it indexed? I wonder if indexing process takes its considerable toll on the CPU or memory. AFAIK, it is supposed to facilitate and accelerate searching, but in my case the only search I launch on drive C: this time and another is that for specific e-mail messages. Searching aside, is indexing essential for normal OS functioning?

Comment: Once a drive is indexed it doesn’t take considerable cpu resources to maintain that index, in fact, doesn’t take considerable resources to even index it in the first place

Comment: @Ramhound Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense to index the Windows system disk.

Otherwise you will have problems with finding products from the Start Menu.

Comment: Good point. It did not occur to me. Thank you. That answers my question, I suppose.